# jQuery .load() not working in IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, encoding, load

I am having trouble with IE 10 and jQuery .load(). I have a PHP page that I load once the website proper has loaded:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#words').html('<div id="loading"><div id="loading-text">Analyzing frequency data...</div><div id="loading-image"><img src="loading.gif"></div></div>');
    $('#words').load('translate.php?character=<?php echo $character1;?>');
});
```

It works fine in Chrome, but in IE the "loading" text appears for about 1 second and disappears, and the translate.php file never loads.

If I change the code to

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#words').html('<div id="loading"><div id="loading-text">Analyzing frequency data...</div><div id="loading-image"><img src="loading.gif"></div></div>');
    $('#words').load('index.php');
});
```

it loads fine. However, if I change the code to:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#words').html('<div id="loading"><div id="loading-text">Analyzing frequency data...</div><div id="loading-image"><img src="loading.gif"></div></div>');
    $('#words').load('translate.php?character=章');
});
```

is still doesn't work.

Also, when I echo the character in the translate.php file it shows up with "?" which leads me to believe there's a character encoding problem. However:

- All pages are encoded "UTF-8 without BOM"
- I have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` tags
- Chinese characters that aren't loaded from translate.php show up fine

Could it be that the jQuery load is stuffing the encoding up in IE only?

I am lost!

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try url encoding the character in the url

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#words').html('<div id="loading"><div id="loading-text">Analyzing frequency data...</div><div id="loading-image"><img src="loading.gif"></div></div>');
    $('#words').load('translate.php?character='+encodeURIComponent('<?php echo $character1;?>'));
});
```