# .load() function in IE10/9 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

In the backend (wordpress) I have the user select an icon, then that outputs a string of text. I use the .icons class to search over all the icons and replace what strings it finds with the corresponding svg. It works great, but in IE9/10 the load function doesn't work and the string does not get replaced.

I have read that other people have had a similiar problem, but when trying to implement a similar fix, none work and the string still gets outputed [ [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/), [Another Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248060/jquery-load-not-working-in-ie10) ].

I haven't had any luck so far so was wondering if anyone could give me better insight.

**JS / JQuery**

```
function icons() {
  $('.icons').each(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var select =  $(this).html();
    var url = location.origin;
    var path = "/wp-content/themes/Proxy-Engine/dist/assets/icons/svg/";
    var ext = ".svg";
    var icon = url+path+select+ext;
    $(this).load(icon, null, function() {
      $('.icons svg g').removeAttr('stroke');
    });
    var loc = location.origin;
    $(this).html(select)
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the value returned by `$(this).html()`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [span.home-nav-icon-1.icons, context: span.home-nav-icon-1.icons]

Comment: Do you get any kind of error or anything in the F12 console when you try it? Do you know if it works in IE11?  Any chance your site is running in compatibility mode for IE?

Comment: What about providing complete minimalistic sample replicating issue?!

Comment: @KevinHeidt works fine in IE11, edge and I'm not in compatibility mode, also no errors are thrown.

Comment: If you comment out the line inside the onload function, do you see the same result?

Comment: Have you try setting timestamp: `$(this).load(icon + "?" + $.now(), function(){...});`? BTW, how do you check the issue comes from `$.fn.load()` method? I would less surpised if it is an issue regarding svg

Comment: I'm also confused about why you are setting $(this).html(select) at the end. Depending on how things end up being processed, you might be overwriting your svg loading. Try commenting out that last line as well and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes it till outputs the same result.

Comment: @Alexsmander: So then your `icon` string you're passing `load` will look like this: `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/Proxy-Engine/dist/assets/icons/svg/span.home-nav-icon-1.icons.svg` -- is that path *really* valid?

Comment: And separately: Why prepend `location.origin`? An origin-relative path (`/wp-content...`) should be equivalent anyway.

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried doing the timestamp on the removeAtrr earlier, I just did it on the .load() and still nothing. I also removed $(this).html(select) and it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Any chance you provide a jsFiddle? And could you try: `$(this).empty().load(...);`?! (with `$(this).html(select)` removed)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: correct the outputted path for one would be: http://proxy-engine/wp-content/themes/Proxy-Engine/dist/assets/icons/svg/book-open-4.svg

Comment: @Alexsmander: I don't see how that aligns with what you said when I asked you what `$(this).html()` returned. I was expecting HTML, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9/10 does not support window.location.origin. I removed url from var icon, and made it a relative path.

Thanks everyone for the help.

```
function icons() {
  $('.icons').each(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var select =  $(this).text();
    var path = "/wp-content/themes/Proxy-Engine/dist/assets/icons/svg/";
    var ext = ".svg";
    var icon = path+select+ext;
    $(this).load(icon, function() {
      $('.icons svg g').removeAttr('stroke');
    });
  });
}
```